# I can't save password of a site in my webview android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, telegram

I am making an app that loads telegram desktop webpage (web.telegram.org) on webview.

I want to log in once. this is my java code (that works for other sites but not for telegram desktop.

```
final WebView   web = (WebView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            WebSettings settings = web.getSettings();
            settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            web.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
            web.getSettings().getJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically();
            web.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            web.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            web.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

            web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);

            web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    //Users will be notified in case there's an error (i.e. no internet connection)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

                }
            });
            web.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
            web.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
```

What should I do? Please help me!

Comment: Why do you need the desktop version of Telegram? Use the standard API, which is thought for the mobile devices, instead.

Comment: I want to use telegram desktop version because i want to show that on a floating window on webview. and that is easier than standard api.

Comment: So easy that you couldn't make it work... And for what concerns a floating window, couldn't you just use a custom DialogFragment, instead?